# How can I detect whether Galaxy S is plugged to a TV or not?

Tags: android, galaxy

I heard TV-out feature is available on Samsung Galaxy S.

Demo video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SU4Czu3LpU

And some android devices supported TV-out with mini HDMI.

Is there any detection & control APIs for TV-out on android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it's vendor specific. You can look at the Logcat if there is an intent sent when HDMI cable is plugged.

Comment: Thank you. Someday, I respect to see common APIs for TV-Out on android platform with you.

Comment: If you are contet with an answer please accept it by clicking checkbox on the left ;)